# Is there a way to render a list without using $scope or $digest in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have this:

```
myApp.controller(function(){

  var list;
  for (var i in data) { // This has more than 5000 objects
     list[i] = new MyObject(data[i]);
  }
  // At this point, it is very fast to populate the list
  $scope.list = list;
  $scope.$apply() // It is here where it hangs for a long time and freezes the app

})
```

Is there a way to avoid this? In my view I'm not doing any changes to those objects. I just have to display them.

Comment: You don't need to be using `$apply()` at all. Are you asking if you can render things in your view without a controller?

Comment: Why do you need to call apply? I have lists that just work but not that big. Also have you looked at one way binding?

Comment: What's driving this call? From your example, it looks like it's on startup, but I'm assuming that's not the case (you've also neglected injecting $scope, declaring data, etc.)

Comment: My bad, you are right, I don't need to call apply(). I guess the problem resides in the ng-repeat, which freezes the app until it finishes the loop. And no, it is not called on startup. It is called with an ng-click. Just made the code more simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are manipulating your list within a controller, you don't need to call $scope.$apply().

> Angular has made sure of one thing, that all its directives and code
>   that is wrapped inside of angulars context, a $apply() cycle is called
>   within the digest loop that it runs continuously.

So in your case, the controller is basically wrapped inside the angulars context, which results in implicit calling of the digest loop which invokes the $apply() function, thereby resulting in your view being updated.

Note: If you wish to call $apply manually, then it would be better if you wrap your list inside of $apply() and invoke it with a 1ms delay, so as to not get a **digest loop is already running error**:

```
$scope.$apply(function( 
       $scope.list = list;
));
```

For more information you can refer the following link:

[Angular JS Apply and Digest Cycle](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest)

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/